# Why does '[[fallthrough]]' need the square brackets '[[]]'?

Tags: c++, c++17

The `switch` statement has commands to manage its flow, which are `break` and `[[fallthrough]]`.

`break` forces the flow to jump out of the `switch` and `[[fallthrough]]` keeps executing commands ignoring the case validation (actually that is the default behavior of `switch`). For example:

```
switch (x) {
       case 0:
              ...statements...
              break;             //will jump to (...after switch statements...)
       case 1:
              ...statements...
              [[fallthrough]];   //don't jump
       case 2:
              ...statements...   //will be executed if x == 1 or x == 2
}
...after switch statements...
```

Why was `[[fallthrough]]` defined with square brackets if `break` wasn't?

*The command `[[fallthrough]]` was introduced in C++17 as indicated at site [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/fallthrough).

Comment: Maybe because this is just for silencing a compiler warning, so it wouldn't be to much sense introducing a new keyword for it. I mean it does not really change the meaning of the code.

Comment: I understand it is more an indication to the compiler, but a new keyword was introduced anyway.

Comment: It's not a keyword: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword

Comment: Adding keywords to a language is enormously difficult, too likely that such a keyword matches an identifier in existing code and thus causes the program to not compile anymore.  Using an [[attribute]] eliminates that risk.

Answer (score 6):

This is an attribute. These attributes already existed in compilers like GCC to give extensions to the language. It could be used like `__attribute__((<attribute_name>))`. They decided this was not just hardly readable, but also problematic in other aspects, so they introduced this `[[<attribute>]]` syntax for clarity and better safety in c++11.

So it is important to note that this double square bracket is not just for `fallthrough`, but for lot of other attribute too like `noreturn` and `carries_dependency`. See [this](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2761.pdf) for more info.

**Update**: Just an interesting note: In LLVM source code there is a macro for this which look like this:

```c
/// LLVM_FALLTHROUGH - Mark fallthrough cases in switch statements.
#if __cplusplus > 201402L && LLVM_HAS_CPP_ATTRIBUTE(fallthrough)
#define LLVM_FALLTHROUGH [[fallthrough]]
#elif LLVM_HAS_CPP_ATTRIBUTE(gnu::fallthrough)
#define LLVM_FALLTHROUGH [[gnu::fallthrough]]
#elif __has_attribute(fallthrough)
#define LLVM_FALLTHROUGH __attribute__((fallthrough))
#elif LLVM_HAS_CPP_ATTRIBUTE(clang::fallthrough)
#define LLVM_FALLTHROUGH [[clang::fallthrough]]
#else
#define LLVM_FALLTHROUGH
#endif
```

Well it uses the `[[fallthrough]]` in it also, but it could be also observed how `__attribute__((fallthrough))` is used if its an older c++ compiler which support this.

Comment: I see, but why it couldn't be just a keyword? I think they aren't necessary and the code would be more elegant (without them)...

Comment: Parsing c++ code is already hard compared to C for example. Introducing new keywords would make it even harder I guess. But thats my opinion on it, not hard fact. Also in the link there are actual reasons why they decided to go with this. See around page 13.

Comment: I think it was a good decision to introduce the fallthrough, what I don't understand is why it needs to be written differently (adding the brackets). Int the end of day, a new keyword was added anyway.

Comment: @TheArquitect If it was made a keyword then every program that has an variable named `fallthrough` would no longer compile. The C++ committee tries very hard not to break decades of existing software. Again it's NOT a keyword and saying so doesn't make it true.

Comment: But it was not added since you can use `fallthrough` as identifier. It is not a keyword. I don't say it would not be nicer to use just that, but this problem is not as simple as @Blastfurnace pointed it out. Also this particular attribute essentially has no effect other than silencing a warning and telling explicitly that you want to fallthrough on purpose. Making new keywords are more problematic than making new attributes. Making a new keyword for this relative "banal" feature would just not worth the down sides.

Comment: Keywords tend to be introduced for features that are important things for the language to support.   Attributes tend to be introduced for things that are desirable or nice-to-have (in this case, giving or suppressing warnings) but that a compiler is permitted to ignore, since they are not essential features of the language.   The `[[]]` syntax indicates, among other things, that a compiler can ignore this.   The burden of a keyword (breaking existing code that uses the new keyword as an identifier) is not justifiable in such cases

Answer (score 2):

`[[fallthrough]]` is syntactic noise. If you remove it the code means exactly the same thing. Its purpose is to tell aggressive compilers that you don't want to get a warning that you might not be smart enough to understand the code you've written.

Those things in double square brackets are **attributes**; the underlying requirement for an attribute is that adding or removing it doesn't change the meaning of the program.

The reason that it's different from `break` is that `break` actually means something: it says that the code has reached the end of the processing for that particular case, so execution should continue **after** the end of the `switch` statement.

An attribute is **not** a keyword. A keyword is **always** treated as a special identifier by the compiler (except when it's inside a quoted string; `"switch"` is just text). Making `fallthrough` a keyword would mean that code like `bool fallthrough = false;` would become ill-formed.

Comment: What the relation of 'you don't want to get a warning that you might not be smart enough to understand the code you're written' and 'to tell aggressive compilers that you don't want to get warning'? If I don't want to get warning and I know where it comes from (because that I use this syntactically noise command/attribute), that means I don't understand the code I wrote?

Comment: @TheArquitect -- the purpose of the annotation is to tell the compiler not to warn you.